# How Can I populate a div if there any change in database using jquery and ajax request in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to populate my div , without refreshing the entire page if there is any change in databse from different online user.

Comment: Using ajax + polling will do it for you

Comment: Hey, How can we make sure that if database is updated? , if not that request is wasted.That is I need  to refresh the div if and only if there is a change in database,

Comment: You'll need to keep track of the last insert id (maybe store it in session) and then poll periodically to check if that has changed. If it has, update the session variable, pull data and update the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){
   // run the ajax function every 10 secs here
   // which will check for fresh updates
   $.ajax({
      .
      .
      .
      success:function(ret)
      {
          //return back either 1 or 0; 1 for new content, 0 for no change
          if(ret == 1)
          {
              // update your div here
          }
      }
   });
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check your database on a given interval. e.g.

```
//checks the database every one minute    
setInterval(function(){
    $.post(variables you want to check,function(){
        if(retrieved variables != old variables){
            update your box;
        }
    });
},60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with asprin's solution, but its better to wait for the previous request to end before you make another request.

```
var req = null;
function call() {
    req = $.ajax({
       .
       .
       .
       success:function(ret)
       {
           //return back either 1 or 0; 1 for new content, 0 for no change
           if(ret == 1)
           {
               // update your div here
           }
       },
       complete: function () {
          setTimeout(function () {
             call();
          }, 5000); // delay half of what of asprin's time

       }
    });
}

function endCall() { // call it when you want to end the updates.
   req.abort();
}
```

Comment: Hmm..not a bad idea.but I think a simple query won't take more than 2 seconds to complete

Comment: but it never depends on your server side code. it always depends on the network and connectivity between client and server?